# How do i convert STDS file to ASCII DEM?

Tags: convert, dem, mac, ascii

I've downloaded several 7.5 minute DEM files from USGS and they have file names like:

1661629.DEM.SDTS.TAR

On MAC these decompress into a folder with serval files having the extension '.DDF'. Is there a shareware program that allows me to convert them to a basic ASCII text DEM file under the Mac OS X operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL is a free geospatial raster translation program that will convert USGS sdts dem to USGS asci dem. A Mac installer is available here [gdal installers](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries).

I'm unfamiliar with a Mac, but you will run gdal_translate.exe from a command line. Something like gdal_translate -of USGSDEM 1661629.DEM.SDTS. -of is the output format. The gdal_translate command help page is here [translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) These are gdal format abbreviations [formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html.)

Comment: thanks. I've downloaded but dont see a new Application. What exactly am I running!

Comment: I found the `gdal_translate.exe` which is installed under the `/Library/Frameworks/` directory. After creating the `~/.bash_profile` and adding the code below it runs from any directory:`export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH` I've managed to run the translator using Mac Terminal: `gdal_translate -of USGSDEM 1663331.DEM.SDTS.TAR.GZ 1663331.DEM` However, i get the error message below: `ERROR 4: 1663331.DEM.SDTS.TAR.GZ' not recognised as a supported file format. `   Am I wrong in thinking it will read the compressed file? What should it be?

Comment: @robertprince-wright - Either uncompress or use the special [GDAL "/vsitar"](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/ReadInZip) virtual filesystem syntax, i.e. `gdal_translate -of USGSDEM /vsitar/1663331.DEM.SDTS.TAR.GZ 1663331.DEM`

Comment: @Luke - thanks, I've uncompressed the files and you end up with about 20 files with the DDL extension. I tried running 'gdal_translate' using the folder name but that fails too. So is there a specific file I need to point to?

Comment: My problem is solved by uncompressing the file and then pointing to the file containing 'CATD'. I presume it has special pointers to the other files.